# SpringbootTest Mock before Autowire

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am trying to unittest a bean, and mock another bean that autowired in constructor.
Mock should be before the autowiring.

Beans:

```
@Component
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA(ClassB b, ClassC c){
        System.out.println("A->" + b.get());
    }
}


@Component
public class ClassB {

    public String get(){
        return "foo";
    }
}

@Component
public class ClassC {
    public ClassC(ClassB b){
        System.out.println("C->" + b.get());
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootTest(
    
        classes = {
                 ClassA.class,
                ClassC.class
})
public class SomeTest {


    @MockBean
    private ClassB b;
    
    @Autowired
    private ClassC c;

    @Autowired
    private ClassA a;


    @BeforeAll
    private void mockB() {
        when(b.get()).thenReturn("koo");

    }

    @Test
    void test() {
       //do some test
    }




}
```

I expect  to see prints:

C->koo
A->koo

but  got:

C->null
A->null

i tried also with MockitoExtension and InjectMocks .

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trick:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeTest.TestConfig.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @MockBean
        private ClassB b;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            when(b.get()).thenReturn("koo");
        }
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private ClassC c;

    @Autowired // you should use @Autowired - do not mock twice
    private ClassB b;

    @Autowired
    private ClassA a;

    @Test
    void test() {
       // do some test
    }
}
```

Note that the `@MockBean` annotation and mockito `when-then` have been moved to `TestConfig`. So you should use `@Autowired` to inject `ClassB` into the test class if it is used there.

Also you don't have to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` because `@SpringBootTest` already has it.

**UPD**

The above example will work if you have a regular Spring Boot Application setup: you have a main class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. If you don't have this class you need to add it to your test code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeTest.TestConfig.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @SpringBootApplication
    public static class DummyApp {
    }

    // the same code as in the example above
}
```

Or you can create `DummyApp` outside this test class in the same package in your test code.

Comment: `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...)` with your test, when I added it , it still prints null

Comment: PostConstruct is called after constructors of ClassA and ClassC

Comment: I got you, @Lamming. You don't have the main class with annotation `@SpingBootApplication` in the production code (`src/main/java`). I've updated my answer